# Golang: Предоставить []string в качестве string аргумента логическому оператору if

Tags: файлы, golang

Задача: Предоставить массив string исключений, массив string расширений в качестве аргумента к оператору if.

Допустим у меня есть

```
fileExt := []string{".exe", ".bin"}
fileExcept := []string{"waste.exe", "unusual.exe"}
```

Я не могу сделать итерацию вида `for _, fext := range fileExt {}` так как под этой итерацией будет ещё несколько итераций, и вместо одной или двух пройденных итераций будет свыше сотни, смотря сколько указано аргументов в []string массивах. Я хочу сделать что-то вроде поиска значений в массиве, то есть `if file.Ext == searchExts([]string{".exe", ".bin"})` -> если в найденных файлах присутствует расширение `.exe` ИЛИ `.bin`, не важно в какой последовательности, будет возвращать результат true. У меня есть функция searchString, но она может искать всего 1 расширение файла, а не список расширений, вот код:

```
func searchString(files []string, target string) string {
    var cFiles string
    sort.Strings(files)

    i := sort.SearchStrings(files, target)
    if i < len(files) && files[i] == target {
        cFiles = files[i]
    }

    return cFiles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужен константный<sup>1</sup> поиск по расширению файла, то так и сделайте:

```golang
exts := map[string]bool{
    ".exe": true,
    ".txt": true,
}

files := []string{
    "foo.txt",
    "bar.exe",
    "baz.xml",
}

for _, f := range files {
    ext := filepath.Ext(f)
    if exts[ext] {
        fmt.Printf("%s matches\n", f)
        continue
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s doesn't match\n", f)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/2_SG1E6X63X.

Из других вариантов разве что регулярные выражения.

<sub>1. Амортизированно.</sub>